# Trying to advise a method from Spring Data JPA repository using aspectJ

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to define a pointcut whose advice will run when method from a Spring Data JPA repository is invoked.

Here is my anonymous pointcut together with the inline advice (from `PliEventManagerAspect`):

```
after(Pli pli) returning: (execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository+.save(Pli)) && args(pli)){
    System.out.println("Caught!!!!");   
}
```

Here the definition for my PliRepository:

```
public interface PliRepository extends GlobalRepository<Pli, Long>, PliRepositoryCustom {
```

and PliRepositoryImpl:

```
public class PliRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements PliRepositoryCustom {
```

and PliRepositoryCustom:

```
public interface PliRepositoryCustom {
```

and lastly GlobalRepository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GlobalRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
```

I have also set the javaagent command line arg. And I have the following aop.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
"-//AspectJ//DTD//EN"
"http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-verbose">
        <include within="org.springframework.data.repository..*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="trc.suivi.aspects.PliEventManagerAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

The above advice, which is supposed to run in LTW since it is advising a class in a jar, is not run at all... I am sure I must make some mistake in the pointcut definition. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed to the following configuration:

**aop.xml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
"-//AspectJ//DTD//EN"
"http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-verbose"></weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="trc.suivi.aspects.PliEventManagerAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Thus the weaver scans all classes.

And **PliEventManagerAspect.aj:**

```
after(Pli pli) returning: (execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository+.save(*)) && args(pli)){
        log.debug("Caught!!!!");  
    }
```

It now works (thanks to Marten from Spring Forums).